# How can I search for a string in a .txt file for NSScanner?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsscanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find next match of a phrase with NSScanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325196/find-next-match-of-a-phrase-with-nsscanner)

I currently have the following code to get a certain piece of code from the UIWebView:

```
    NSURL *requestTimetableURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dhsb.org/index.phtml?d=201435"];
    NSLog(@"Loaded Timetable");
    NSError *error;
    NSString *page = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestTimetableURL 
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];

    [webView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:requestTimetableURL];

    NSString* Period1;

    NSScanner *htmlScanner =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    [htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"<P align=center><STRONG><FONT color=#c00000>" intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner scanString:@"<P align=center><STRONG><FONT color=#c00000>" intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period1];
```

How can I scan a .txt file (which contains the string like above) for the code?

E.G. `[htmlScanner scanUpToString:teststring intoString:NULL];`

(teststring being the .txt file)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you perhaps mean: how do I load a .txt file into an NSString so that I can scan it?

Comment: sorry if I didn't word it very well, but yes, that's what I meant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];

You can see examples here:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle

if you don't want to read from your bundle (your app) but from your documents dir, use:

```
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError* error=nil;
NSURL* docsurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];
NSURL* fileUrl = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileUrl.path];
```